# Type is not found in context during BulkInsert in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I am trying to use the `BulkInsert` in EF6 in C#.

I have a list of extended `DataModel`. I'll do an convert back to the type of the database.

```
List<pc_d_zeiten> ImportZeitenListe = pc_d_zeiten_extendend.ConvertExtendedModelBack((from item in zeitenListe where item.DoInsert == true select item).ToList());
```

Calling insert:

```
public void InsertZeitenModelListe(List<pc_d_zeiten> zeitenListe)
{
     db.BulkInsert(zeitenListe);           
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I am calling the `dbContext.BulkInsert(List<entity>)` an exception is being fired:

> Type 'PROCESSPC_Core.PZE.Model.pc_d_zeiten_extendend' is not found in
>   context 'PROCESSPC_Core.DAL.ProcessPCEntities'

I did update the MappingApi, rebuild my project. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Firstly, what is `BulkInsert`, that's not part of Entity Framework by default? Secondly, the error doesn't appear to match the code you show here, are you sure this is correct?

Comment: The error appears while calling db.BulkInsert()....

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have two DataContexts in my project. One works and one does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It means the type is not recognized as any kind of entity or entity subclass in a table per hierarchy.

If you have a type marked as a DbSet in your context.... that type can inherit from as many classes as you want.  Subclasses of that class, however, have to be registered as discriminated types.  If you have some shared class deriving from the DbSet type that's not registered as a discriminated type, then it won't be found.